# webpack - how to inject the generated bundle filename in specific location in the body using the plugin html-webpack-plugin

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I have a webapp that is processed by webpack and produces a bundled file with a hash in the filename e.g. `./app.bundle.69864e89b3c785f87cc0.js`.
I want to populate this filename into a generated .html file, based on a template .ejs file.
I'm using the webpack plugin `html-webpack-plugin`.
I read the html-webpack-plugin documentation and several html-webpack-plugin related tutorials **but it is still not clear to me, how to do it?**

- The [webpack cache-busting tutorial](https://medium.com/@tomaskoutsky/hey-webpack-can-you-bust-my-cache-21350f951220)
  populates the hashed filenames at the end of the body section.
  But in my case I need to inject the hashed filename `app.bundle.69864e89b3c785f87cc0.js` **in a specific location in the middle of the body section**.
- I read the plugin [official documentation](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options)
  and it is not clear to me how should I run the script [build-examples.js](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/main/examples/build-examples.js) to build all the examples, or how to build a specific example.
  When trying to build a specific example, I get an error:

```
mkdir -p ~/webpackRelated/
git clone https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin.git
pushd ~/webpackRelated/html-webpack-plugin/examples/template-parameters/
webpack

webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'lodash'
```

I basically want to achieve what was asked in [here](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/290).
I set `inject:false` according to the comment [here](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/290#issuecomment-210297393) to not generate the template.
The comment also points to an [example template](https://github.com/jaketrent/html-webpack-template/blob/86f285d5c790a6c15263f5cc50fd666d51f974fd/index.html)

```
...
<body>
<% for (var chunk in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks) { %>
<script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[chunk].entry %>"></script>
<% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

but does not show how to set the config file.

Below are my source files:

- webpack.config.take1.js - the webpack conf file
- index.template.ejs - the template file
- index.html - the final file, where I expect the hashed name app.bundle.69864e89b3c785f87cc0.js to be populated but it is not.

I run webpack with the following command:

```
webpack --config webpack/webpack.config.take1.js
```

This creates a hashed version `./app.bundle.69864e89b3c785f87cc0.js`, but I cannot find how to inject the hashed name into a specific location in the `index.template.ejs` file.

**How could I populate the generated hashed bundled filename, into an existing template?**
Can someone provide an example of the template, and the webpack config file?

Thanks,

Avner

---

The webpack config file - webpack.config.take1.js

```
cat webpack.config.take1.js
const webpack = require('../webClient/node_modules/webpack')
var path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('../webClient/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    context: path.resolve('js/'),
    entry: {
        app: './main.js',
        css: "../../css/style.css",
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: 'public'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
                }                
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }],
            }
        ]    
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: './index.html',
            template: './index.template.ejs',
            templateParameters: {
                content1: 'foo1',
                content2: 'foo2',
            },
            inject: false,
            chunks: ['output.chunkFilename'],
        })
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('build/bundles_prod'),
        filename: "./[name].bundle.[chunkhash].js" ,
        chunkFilename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
        publicPath: 'build',
        // library: "lib1",
        // libraryTarget: "umd",
    }
};
```

The template file - index.template.ejs

```
cat index.template.ejs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
...
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/V1/css/style.css">
...
    </head>
    <body>
...
       {% if flask_env == "development" %}
...
       <p><%= content1 %></p>
       <% for (var chunk in htmlWebpackPlugin.chunks) { %>
       <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.chunks[chunk] %>"></script>
       <% } %>
       <p><%= content2 %></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The populated file index.html

```
cat index.html
<p>foo1</p>

I expected to see here, the follwoing line, but nothing shows up between foo1, and foo2
<script src="app.bundle.69864e89b3c785f87cc0.js"></script>

<p>foo2</p>
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I'll not provide whole solution. I had it stored somewhere, but `find` didn't find it :)
I was actually experimenting with the `ejs` file or you can dump on the screen the `htmlWebpackPlugin` variable and check what is in and use.